# Problema Scanner y return

Tags: java

tengo un problema que planteé anteriormente y como me comentaron, me falto mostrar código y ser más específico así que allá voy.
Tengo que introducir la variable `precio` por Scanner en un método, y quiero enviar posteriormente esa variable `precio` al `main` para usarla en el 2º método. Por otra parte también quisiera usar solo un `return` para redondear dos cifras pero no veo como.
Mi código:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Precios {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
              
      preciosPorcentajes(teclado);
      preciosSemanales(teclado, precio);
      
   }

   public static void preciosPorcentajes(Scanner teclado) {
      System.out.print("Introduce precio: ");
      double precio = teclado.nextDouble();
      
      for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        double porcentaje = 1.0;
        double intereses = precio * porcentaje / 100 * i;
        
        System.out.print(i + " años \t" + intereses * (1.0) + "(1.0%) \t" + intereses * (1.5) + "(1.5%) \t");
      }      
   }
   
   public static void preciosSemanales(Scanner teclado, double precio) {
   
      System.out.print("Introduce el Precio anual: ");
      double precioAnual = teclado.nextDouble();
      System.out.print("Introduce la tasa: ");
      double tasas = teclado.nextDouble();
      System.out.print("Introduce la duración: ");
      int semanas = teclado.nextInt();
   
      for(int i = 1; i <= semanas; i++) {
         double intereses = precio * tasaInteres / 100;
         intereses = redondear(precio, intereses);
         System.out.println("Semana " + i);
         System.out.println("\t Precio Anual: " + (precio));
         System.out.println("\t Intereses: " + intereses);
         precio += intereses + precioAnual;
         precio = redondear(precio, intereses);
      }   
   }    
   public static double redondear(double precio, double intereses) {
   double num = Math.round(precio * 100) / 100.0;
   double num = Math.round(intereses * 100) / 100.0;
   return num;
   }
}
```

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: No veo la lógica del código. Dices que debes devolver `precio` al `main`, pero en `preciosPorcentajes()` no estableces un precio realmente, lo pides por teclado y luego haces unos cálculos dentro de un bucle que no se entiende qué son. ¿Podrías explicar cuál es el propósito de ese método y qué es lo que debe devolver? Por otra parte, *void* significa *vacío* y se pone en métodos que no devuelven nada. Si ese método debe devolver algo no debes declararlo como `void`, sino como del tipo de dato que debe devolver y hacer un `return` de ese dato.

Comment: No sé si esto es un ejercicio. Lo fundamental es que no se entiende qué debe hacer el método, eso no lo explicas en la pregunta, y el propósito de un método es hacer algo. Por otra parte, si vas a usar `precio` en varias partes del programa, sería mejor declararlo como miembro de la clase, así lo tendrás disponible allí donde lo necesites, y lo mismo el `Scanner`.

Comment: @A.Cedano hola, efectivamente lo que quiero es usar el `precio` que meto por teclado, exactamente esa cantidad en el otro metodo `preciosSemanales`. De momento es `void` porque no devuelve nada, pero si me dices que haga un `return` lo pasaré a `double`. Por otra parte que me dices de mi otro problema, el redondeo de dos cantidades, como las devolvería usando un único `return`.

Comment: El método sólo puede devolver objetos de un tipo, si quieres devolver varios objetos de ese tipo puedes usar por ejemplo un `HashMap` o un `ArrayList` o un array, donde metes los diferentes objetos. Otra posibilidad sería crear otro método que calcule y devuelva ese otro valor... Pero esto no tiene sentido, es mejor declarar esos objetos como miembros de la clase, así, sólo los vas asignando y usando en los diferentes métodos, porque al ser miembros de la clase, tendrás acceso a ellos desde cualquier parte.

Comment: @A.Cedano estoy empezando y todavía no he pasado de usos simples, lo que me sigue bloqueando es lo del `precio` lo intento hacer con un `return` y no lo consigo, no sé que hago mal, si me pudieses proporcionar un ejemplo te lo agradecería.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Tengo que introducir la variable precio por Scanner en un método, y
> quiero enviar posteriormente esa variable precio al main para usarla
> en el 2º método.

En ese caso, el método no debe ser declarado como `void`, que significa *vacío*, o lo que es lo mismo, no retorna nada. Debes indicar que el método retorna un objeto del tipo del `return`.

Algo así:

```
public static double preciosPorcentajes(Scanner teclado) {
   System.out.print("Introduce precio: ");
   return teclado.nextDouble();
}
```

Ahora, en la llamada, harías esto:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
          
   double precio = preciosPorcentajes(teclado);
   // Usar precio para lo que necesites
   preciosSemanales(teclado, precio);
  
}
```

Pero, parece que en `preciosPorcentajes()` se debe determinar también el interés. En ese caso, varias soluciones son posibles:

- Dado que tanto `precio` como `interes` son del mismo tipo, puedes declarar un array para almacenar ambos valores y devolverlos desde el método
- O puedes meterlos en un `HashMap`
- O puedes meterlos en un `ArrayList`
- O puedes crear un nuevo método que calcule el interés
- O, lo mejor de todo, declarar tanto `precio` como `interes` como miembros de la clase si piensas usarlos en varios métodos de la misma

Dado que no conozco el contexto, si es un ejercicio, etc, no puedo ahondar más en esto, proponiéndote la solución más óptima. Además, no se entiende bien el concepto `interes` en tu contexto, pues usas un bucle, como si deberían aplicar diferentes intereses según contextos diversos. Como dije en un comentario, un método es para hacer algo y es fundamental, cuando programas, tener claro la finalidad de ese método, **qué debe hacer** y eso debe quedar expuesto con claridad en la pregunta.